# [C#/VB.NET]Communicating with closed source WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I've got a question regarding communcation with another application. I wrote a little application that checks if specific persons play a specific game (League of Legends) and if so, it creates something called the spectator code which looks like this:
    "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.15\deploy\League        of Legends.exe" "8394" "LoLLauncher.exe" "" "spectator spectator.eu.lol.riotgames.com:8088   nQCxZ8ayLm369T1DwEejG/QlEoR+JyZK 1407774989 EUW1"

In another application which is NOT developed by me called "BaronReplays"  (http://puu.sh/7VBFj.png) (a WPF application) you can enter this code under File (http://puu.sh/7VBEM.jpg) -> Analyze Command and enter the Code (http://puu.sh/7VBGD.png), after that click ok. Then this game will be recorded. I want to automate the process of entering this code in my application, so that my application sends the code to BaronReplays (without it being maximized and using SendKeys). I tried SendMessage, but that didn't work out because the keys aren't recognized by BaronReplays... Do you think there's any other way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way... As the WPF application is coded with the .NET framework, it is compiled to MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language). This means you can use a decompiler such as ILSpy to decompile and view the code of BaronReplays. This will give you some idea of how BaronReplays works so you can implement the same ideas into your own code project...

Hope this helped!

Rodit

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but this is impossible, because it's very complicated how replays in League of Legends work and BaronReplays is obfuscated so it's very very hard to understand. And they don't allow other people to decompile - which I totally understand.

Comment: @MaximilianBöther I'm sorry to hear that... Maybe you can get in touch with the developers of BaronReplays and ask them to help you out? If not, I'm afraid I cannot help you much more! Regards, Rodit